# Bootstrap button doesn't have an outline on click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've seen many Bootstrap button examples where I click on the button and it shows an outline. I have tried to copy it, but my button does not show the outline.

What is the problem?

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Your button is exactly what is shown in the docs for Bootstrap v5. "I've seen many Bootstrap button examples" It would be worth to include a picture of what you have seen. Maybe you are talking about Bootstrap v4 buttons?

Comment: The documentation might help here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons - In Bootstrap 5.3 has no mechanism to do this by default

Comment: "Couldn't find the requested file /dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD in bootstrap." It says this when im trying to open link.Are you sure you wroted true link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you are using is bootstrap 5.3 alpha so with this version bootstrap has changed its design principles. One of them is an outline at the click of a button.
If you want an outline you can go to it older version.

1. Bootstrap 5 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin:10px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
</div>
```

2. Bootstrap 5.3 Alpha (https://getbootstrap.com)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="margin:10px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of bootstrap that you are using seems to not have this outline as can be seen on their website. The latest version that seems to have the outline is version 5.1.3.

Has it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/

Does not have it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/

Answer (score 0):

You did not include an example of what you have seen. By your description, I may try to guess your complain is about the default theme for [Bootstrap v5 buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons/) in opposition to [Bootstrap v4 buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/buttons/), which show an outline when clicked. Version 5 does show the outline only when navigating by using <kbd>Tab</kbd>. In fact, that occurs in the example of your question: click does not outline, but tab navigation does.

In this case, you have a few options:

1. Keep with version 5 and its default behaviour.
2. Downgrade to version 4 to get the desired behaviour.
3. Create a custom CSS to get back the outline.
4. Create or get a custom theme.